# Find by element in Collection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm working on a Recipe application in Java, using JPA. I need to create a findBy method to find a Recipe by Ingredient id. I tried:

```
List<Recipe> findByRecipeIngredientsIngredientIdEqual(Long ingredientId);
```

But it doesn't work

Here are the classes:

```
public class Recipe {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class RecipeIngredient {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("ingredientId")
    private Ingredient ingredient;

}

public class Ingredient {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken the `Equal` clause is not necessary and you should use the following:

```
List<Recipe> findByRecipeIngredientsIngredientId(Long ingredientId);
```